# How to log in via OAuth so a cron job can run Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, gmail

How to log in via OAuth to Gmail so a cron job can run
I using this https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail

Comment: You'll probably have to request the `offline` permission, so you'll get a refresh token and can interact with gmail without userinteraction

Comment: @FabianBettag developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server you mean this ?

Comment: Yes, specifically this section: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline